# Repairing section of black fiber board

Tags: electrical, walls, framing, vinyl-siding

I had to remove some siding and black board to make some electrical repairs. What is the proper way to close it up? Can I just screw in a section of OSB between the two studs and put siding up? The black board doesn’t have a house wrap, so I’m not sure what to do with the OSB to protect it and keep water out.

Comment: Usually they use tar paper if not using modern house wrap.  Coat the OSB with roof tar.